# AccessibilityService not respond when I reboot my phone

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

At first my AccessibilityService works well, but when I reboot my Galaxy S10, the service is closed , then I open it manually. I think the service will work same as before , but it doesn't respond anything , even the "onServiceConnected()" is not called.

I tried my code on Galaxy S10 , Android 9 , One UI 1.1 .

```
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:packageNames="com.android.settings"
    android:description="@string/xxx"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeWindowContentChanged|typeWindowStateChanged"
    android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault|flagReportViewIds"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackAllMask"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried my code in an Android 9 phone as well, even my service not shown in settings->accessibility...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.reviewassistant">


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/reviewassistant"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">


        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>



        <service android:name=".AssistantService"
            android:enabled = "true"
            android:exported = "true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="anroid.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
                android:resource="@xml/config_accessibility"/>

        </service>

    </application>


</manifest>




<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:description="@string/app_name"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeAllMask"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackAllMask"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
    android:notificationTimeout="100"
    android:accessibilityFlags="flagReportViewIds"
    android:packageNames="com.example.reviewassistant"
    android:settingsActivity="com.example.reviewassistant.MainActivity"
    />
```